# Split file F into M parts, recover file F from N of those M parts

Tags: files, archive, redundancy

I want to split a file into *M* parts, such that I can recover the file from *N* of those *M* parts. (Where *M>N*, and I get to choose both *M* and *N*).

For example:

1. I have `FILE.IMG`
2. I split `FILE.IMG` into *M=3* parts.
3. I set the split-time encoding to allow me to recover the file from any *N=2* of those parts.
4. The encoding/splitting is finished, I now have `FILE.IMG.1`, `FILE.IMG.2` and `FILE.IMG.3`
5. I delete any one of those three new files, and yet I can still recover the original `FILE.IMG`

I use Ubuntu Linux, and hope for an answer using `apt-get`-able tools thereon.

Comment: This site is about helping other people with their computer problems, not about doing other people's assignments and tasks.  If you need help, at least show us what you've done so far and what doesn't work.

Comment: Might want to start with [par2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive)

Comment: For M-N=1or2, look at RAID5 and RAID6. You could use mdadm on loop devices to work with files instead of disks.

Comment: I discovered and am now using the [gfshare](http://www.digital-scurf.org/software/libgfshare) (`apt-get install libgfshare-bin`) implementation of [Shamir's Secret Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing), though [par2](https://github.com/Parchive/par2cmdline) would likely also work.